# При замене текста в блоке оставляет пустую строку

Tags: jquery, ajax

В общем вопрос в заголовке поста, при аякс запросе в `div`, где нужно заменить текст, при замене скрипт выводит пустую строчку перед информацией... При просмотре кода элемента отображается как "". Как от этого  избавиться? Спасибо!

вот так делаем запрос

```
$('#form').change(function(){ //отправляем данные из конструктора
var m_method=$(this).attr('method'); //берем из формы метод передачи данных
var m_action=$(this).attr('action'); //получаем адрес скрипта на сервере, куда нужно отправить форму
var m_data=$(this).serialize(); //получаем данные, введенные пользователем в формате input1=value1&input2=value2...,

    $.ajax    ({
        type    : m_method,
        url : '/php/constructor/error.php',
            data    : m_data,
            cache   : false,
        async   : true,
        success : function(result){           
              $("#errors").html(result);     
            }
    });
```

выдает следующее:

```
<b id="errors">
""
﻿<h2>заголовок!</h2>
<div>Текст!</div>
</b>
```

правда "" не выводятся на экран, вместо этого перевод на новую строку

данные в utf-8

файл error.php:

```
<?
$___notjson=1;
include 'inc/matras_cfg.php';
$i_err="1";

//проверяем форму заказа на ошибки
if (!$block){ 
$error .= "<div>".$i_err++.". Вы не указали какой тип матраса хотите!</div>";};
if ($block == "non" AND !$main_mtr){
$error .= "<div>".$i_err++.". Вы не указали какой тип матраса хотите!</div>";};

if ($block != "non"){
if (!$matras['latex'] AND !$matras['real_latex'] AND !$matras['ppu'] AND !$matras['memory'] AND !$matras['strutto'] AND !$matras['cocos']){
$error .= "<div>".$i_err++.". Вы не указали ни одного верхнего наполнителя!</div>";
$error .= "<div>Рекомендую выбрать в качестве одного из верхних наполнителей - мемориформ или натуральный латекс.</div>";};

if (!$matras['latex_down'] AND !$matras['real_latex_down'] AND !$matras['ppu_down'] AND !$matras['memory_down'] AND !$matras['strutto_down'] AND !$matras['cocos_down']){
$error .= "<div>".$i_err++.". Вы не указали ни одного нижнего наполнителя!</div>";};
};

//если есть ошибки, выводим их
if ($error){
print "<h2>Обратите внимание!</h2>";
if ($i_err <= "2"){ //если одна ошибка, убираем нумерацию
$error =  str_replace('1.', "", $error);
print $error;
}else{
print "<div>".$error."</div>";};
};

//если ошибок нет, выводим сообщение
if (!$error){ 
print "<h2>Отличный выбор!</h2>";
print "<div id='noprint'>Этот матрас прослужит вам очень долго! ";
if ($matras[memory]){
$helper = "Благодаря выбранному наполнителю - <b>мемориформ</b>, Вам будет удобно и комфортно спать на Вашем матрасе!";};
if ($matras[cocos]){
$helper = "Благодаря выбранному наполнителю - <b>кокосовая койра</b>, Ваш матрас будет достаточно жестким, что весьма полезно для спины.";};
if ($matras[real_latex]){
$helper = "Благодаря выбранному наполнителю - <b>натуральный латек</b>, Вы гарантируете себе экологически чистый продукт!";};

print "<div>".$helper."</div>";

?></div><?
};

//print $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."<br>";
?>
```

Comment: телепаты в отпуске

Comment: Какой тип данных приходит в ответе на ajax-запрос? Как формируете сам ответ? Как вставляете контент в блок?

Comment: Код в студию. Ибо Здесь Матрен и Ванг нету, угадать, что там вы написали не можем.

Comment: добавил код выше...

Comment: @Dimastik86, по своему коментарию выше, я так и не увидел некоторых уточнений. Это тот случай, когда ваш JS-код, интересует меня в последнюю очередь. Что вы в ответе на ajax-запрос получаете, то и выводиться на экран. Поэтому искать откуда "растут ноги", надо в первую очередь в файле *error.php*.

Comment: error.php код добавил выше

Comment: *...нервно кашляет...* )) Бог с ним, как вы это дело организовываете, хотя вещи типа **$i_err="1";** - "радуют". При всём этом, исходя из кода, который вы показали, никакие лишние символы не должны попадать в ответ. Уже боюсь вас спрашивать, что в коде файла "matras_cfg.php", поэтому сами посмотрите - нет ли там чего-нидуть что выводиться на экран: **print 'что-либо';** или **echo 'что-то еще';**. А может быть, у вас до показанного кода, что-нибудь таким образом выводится.

P.S. Кстати, если у вас до открывающего тега "<?" (*праильно "<?php"*) есть пустые строки, то они так же будут выведены!

Comment: нет, в это-то и дело!

Comment: а ещё совет - заведите привычку не использовать short open tags (`<?`) используйте `<?php` сейчас почти все дистры по умолчанию ставят в php.ini `short_open_tags=Off` и в конце `?>` не делайте

Comment: по неработе - у вас наверное ошибка где-то а display_errors выключен

Comment: про <?php понял, а что в конце ставить? вместо ?>

Comment: ничего не надо ставить,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Или я неправильно понял вопрос, или я проблема в вёрстке, или же я сыграю в экстрасенса и вам может подойти метод `.trim()`, удаляющий пробелы и переводы строк в начале и конце строковой переменной.

Comment: Ииии.. ЭТО ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ ОТВЕТ!

Comment: ок, почитаю! )) я только учусь ;)

Comment: не получилось у меня тримом, добавил код в топикстарт, посмотрите...